# DIV alignment and position

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get my front page areas underneath each other, at the moment I have the next area underneath but positioned to the left.

I want to be able to change the next areas background color.

Any tips on the HTML/css?

Sorry about the long tags in the CSS I am doing a child theme with Avada in wordpress.

```
<div id="main-header">

 What can we do for You and Your Company

    </div>

    <div id="main-index-container">

    <div id="index-container">

    <div class="services">

    <img src="http://localhost:8888/Enviroble/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Social-Media-Marketing.png" alt="social-media" height="91" width="60"> </img>
                        <h1>Energy Audits</h1>
         <p> Nec nisl pede congue, ipsum nec justo cras bibendum, dui quis. Pretium rutrum elit malesuada sodales, in id et, sodales ut ipsum leo risus.</p>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="index-container">

    <div class="services">

    <img src="http://localhost:8888/Enviroble/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Social-Media-Marketing.png" alt="social-media" height="91" width="60"> </img>
                        <h1>Energy Audits</h1>
         <p> Nec nisl pede congue, ipsum nec justo cras bibendum, dui quis. Pretium rutrum elit malesuada sodales, in id et, sodales ut ipsum leo risus.</p>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="index-container">

    <div class="services">

    <img src="http://localhost:8888/Enviroble/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Social-Media-Marketing.png" alt="social-media" height="91" width="60"> </img>
                        <h1>Energy Audits</h1>
         <p> Nec nisl pede congue, ipsum nec justo cras bibendum, dui quis. Pretium rutrum elit malesuada sodales, in id et, sodales ut ipsum leo risus.</p>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="index-container">

    <div class="services">

    <img src="http://localhost:8888/Enviroble/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Social-Media-Marketing.png" alt="social-media" height="91" width="60"> </img>
                        <h1>Energy Audits</h1>
         <p> Nec nisl pede congue, ipsum nec justo cras bibendum, dui quis. Pretium rutrum elit malesuada sodales, in id et, sodales ut ipsum leo risus.</p>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="index-container">

    <div class="services">

    <img src="http://localhost:8888/Enviroble/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Social-Media-Marketing.png" alt="social-media" height="91" width="60"> </img>
                        <h1>Energy Audits</h1>
         <p> Nec nisl pede congue, ipsum nec justo cras bibendum, dui quis. Pretium rutrum elit malesuada sodales, in id et, sodales ut ipsum leo risus.</p>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="index-container">

    <div class="services">

    <img src="http://localhost:8888/Enviroble/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Social-Media-Marketing.png" alt="social-media" height="91" width="60"> </img>
                        <h1>Energy Audits</h1>
         <p> Nec nisl pede congue, ipsum nec justo cras bibendum, dui quis. Pretium rutrum elit malesuada sodales, in id et, sodales ut ipsum leo risus.</p>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="index-container-second">      
    <div id="wrapper">

      <div id ="similar">
    <div id="text">

        <h1>Learn More</h1> 
    <h1>About us and our solutions...</h1>
    <h4>We offer the product, skills and services, looking for an effective way of undertaking sustainability audits or too implement environmental initiatives.</h4>

    <p>Arcu tempor scelerisque mollis, cras sapien, et dolor scelerisque tempor placerat, aliquam velit et sed vitae. Lectus ullamcorper turpis dictum, augue vulputate est ullamcorper turpis est.
    Eegestas egestas ligula hendrerit, ante facilisis. Elementum volutpat eget, tellus vel mauris sapien luctus a, at aenean erat non non nulla, lorem amet, ligula justo amet. Nec lectus. Ut sociis pulvinar erat erat in sollicitudin, magna lectus phasellus, orci libero non. Suspendisse facilisis blandit porttitor. Nibh enim, ligula blandit commodo tristique blandit id et.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    /* Index page title container boxes */

div#main-header p {
    color:#ffffff !important;
    font-size:26px;
    padding-top:85px;
    text-align:center; 
    }

    /* Index page container boxes */

div.post-content 
    div#main-index-container{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:940px;
    height:100%;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    clear:right;
    }


div#index-container{
    width:350px;
    height:250px; 
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    background-color: #4f5455;
    }

div#index-container div.index-container-image div.index-container-header{
    Width: 280px;
    height:auto px;
    }

div#index-container div.services h1{
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
    padding-top:0px;
    text-align:center; 
    margin-bottom: 0em !important:
    line-height:5px !important;
    }


div#main-index-container div#index-container div.services h1 {
    line-height:5px !important;
    }

div#index-container div.services p {
    color:#ffffff !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center; 
    padding-top:-10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-left:18px;
    padding-right:18px;
    line-height:20px !important; 
    margin-bottom:0em !important:
    }

div.post-content ul#servicesli {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 16px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        width: 218px;
    }

div#index-container {
     width:250px;
     float:left;}

div#index-container div.services p img {
     display:block;
     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;

    }

    /* Index page container 2 about us */

div#index-container-second{
    float:left;
    height:600px;
    width:960px;
    clear:left;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;}

div#index-container-second div#wrapper div#similar {
    width:100%;

    }

div#index-container-second div#wrapper div#similar div#text {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a different background color for each area, you must have a different `id` in html for each area, to edit it individually by CSS.

Here an example:
HTML

```
<div id="index-container-2">
```

CSS

```
div#index-container-2 {
 width: 350px;
 height: 250px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
 background-color: #336472; /*THIS IS TO CHANGE THE BACKGROUND COLOR*/
}
```